# Why is the value of the answer of an array multiplication being displayed as a memory value?

Tags: c++

R is a square array with values input by the user and this code is meant to calculate R*R.

```
int answers[M][M];

for(int i = 0; i < M; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < M; k++)
        {
            answers[i][j] += R[i][k] * R[k][j];
        }
    }
}
```

When I use printf to display the values of answers it gives me a bunch of what I think are memory values:

```
for(int i = 0; i < M; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ", answers[i][j]);
        if(j == (M-1))
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1606416087 32777 
3311 23
```

Comment: What are you expecting?  Have you used a debugger to verify `R` has the expected values?

Comment: `if(j == (M-1)) printf("\n");` - why not just move the `printf` outside the loop?

Comment: The values of R are as expected. The if statement is more to just show in the output how the matrix looks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your `answers` array has automatic storage duration, is not initialized, and contains indeterminate values before you start the matrix multiplication. If you change the definition to:

```
int answers[M][M] = {};
```

every element will be value initialized to 0.

If these are Variable Length Arrays (VLAs), a non-standard C++ extension, this initialization method won't work and you'll need to use loops instead.

```
for(int i = 0; i < M; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        answers[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought something like that might've been the case but all I get when I try to initialize the array like that is "variable-sized object may not be initialized". Thanks for the help!

Comment: @G.Coo Oh, you are right. Variable Length Arrays (VLAs) are non-standard in C++ but are an extension with some compilers. You'll need old-fashioned loops instead.

Comment: Ah, you were right, the answers array was not initialized properly and I think using '+=' before it actually had a value was causing the problems, Thanks!